# Convert to answer

Tags: feature-request

Not sure if this has been suggested before. But does anyone else think that there should be a feature to convert a comment to a answer?

So you are talking to the OP and then suggest what to do and it turns out to be the answer. It would be great if we or the OP can recommend that comment to be the answer then it gets convert to an answer.

Comment: Just poke the commenter and ask them to do it. If they don't, and you are annoyed, add your own.